# Is it possible to use methods on decorators?

Tags: python, decorator, aiortc

I was looking around the aiortc examples when I notice a decorator that has a method on it:

```
@pc.on("datachannel")
    def on_datachannel(channel):
    ...
```

I don't really understand how this work or what does this code do. I've been searching about decorators and I know it's possible to have class decorators but none about using methods. Can anyone elaborate on this?

Comment: A decorator is a function that accepts a function and returns a function. There's no difference whether that's a standalone function or an object method.

Comment: @deceze I saw your comment (under the deleted answer) that `@pc.on` is the decorator. Is it really? Is `pc.on` not just *returning* the *actual* decorator, when called with the argument `"datachannel"`? In other words, (the result of) `pc.on("datachannel")` is the decorator?

Comment: @superbrain You can debate that all day long. If you use it as `@...`, it's a decorator.

Comment: @deceze Well you said "a decorator is a function". I don't think `@pc.on` is a function. Otherwise I should be able to do `exec('@pc.on')` without getting a *syntax* errror. Maybe you meant `pc.on`, but that one doesn't fulfill "accepts a function", as it accepts a string (apparently).

Comment: @deceze To clarify, your comment was "`@pc` is not the decorator, `@pc.on` is.". So now you're saying that the first part of that, and thus the whole complaint, was wrong.

Comment: @super I don't think it's terribly productive to discuss the nuances of a deleted comment tersely trying to correct a wrong statement. `pc` certainly isn't a decorator, it's just some object. `pc.on` is more of a decorator. Depending on how it is implemented, you may be able to apply `@pc.on` directly on a function, making it *the decorator*. If it accepts (optional?) arguments, then you can discuss whether it's a "decorator accepting arguments" or *a function returning a decorator*. The distinction is somewhat arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foo
def bar(): ...
```

This syntax is merely sugar for this:

```
def bar(): ...
bar = foo(bar)
```

So, this:

```
@pc.on('datachannel')
def on_datachannel(channel): ...
```

is the same as:

```
def on_datachannel(channel): ...
on_datachannel = pc.on('datachannel')(on_datachannel)
```

`pc` is some object, `pc.on` is a method on it, `pc.on('datachannel')` calls it and it returns a function, `pc.on('datachannel')(on_datachannel)` calls that returned function passing it the `on_datachannel` function.

The implementation of `pc.on` is something like this:

```
class PC:
    def on(self, event):
        ...
        def wrapper(fn):
            ...
            def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                ...
                fn(*args, **kwargs)

            return inner_wrapper

        return wrapper

pc = PC()
```

All that inner part is entirely a regular decorator accepting arguments. That it's defined on a class makes no difference to it.